# NSFileManager createFile Failed

Tags: objective-c

```
NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath;

if (str_FolderName!=nil){
    filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/%@",str_FolderName,str_FileName]];
} else {
    filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",str_FileName]];
}

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSMutableDictionary *data;

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: filePath])
{
    //file is exist
    data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

} else {
    BOOL Success = [fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    // sometime return YES, sometime return NO <<< this is my question
    if(Success == YES){
        data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    }else{ 
        data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];            
    }
}

for (uint32_t u32_Cnt=0;u32_Cnt<arr_Keys.count;u32_Cnt++) {
    [data setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[marr_Data objectAtIndex:u32_Cnt]] forKey:[arr_Keys objectAtIndex:u32_Cnt]];
}

if ([data writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES])
{
    NSLog(@"[Save OK]");

    return DEF_PASS;
} else {
    NSLog(@"[Save Fail]");  <<<<   now happened
}
```

If I have checked file is not exist, then i want to create file as filepath

My device sometime success, sometime failed

Filepath is as below:

> @"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx/Documents/mfolder/myfile"

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update some of your code. I put proper allocation of **NSFilemanager** and its work for me. You can have issue in file path or filemanager object.

```
 NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath;

    if (str_FolderName!=nil){
        filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/%@",str_FolderName,str_FileName]];
    }else{
        filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",str_FileName]];
    }
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSMutableDictionary *data;
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: filePath])
    {
        //file is exist
        data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    }
    else
    {
        if (str_FolderName!=nil){
            NSString *strDicPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",str_FolderName]];
            // You need to create director before creating file.
            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:strDicPath])
            {
                NSError *error;
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:strDicPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder
            }

        }
        BOOL Success = [fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
        // sometime return YES, sometime return NO <<< this is my question
        if(Success == YES){
            data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        }else{ 
            data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];            
        }
    }
```

I also check this code in simulator and device both.

For writing string into file:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *stringToWrite = @"1\n2\n3\n4";
[stringToWrite writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Comment: the different is my path contain a folder name, then i test it is success creat file without folder, but it is failed create file with a folder ...

Comment: Can you give your it?

Comment: filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/%@",str_FolderName,str_FileName]];

Comment: You get FALSE becuase, when you try to create with folder and file name both, then you have to create dictionary also. Let me update code.

Comment: so you mean  i can't create file with dolder?okay ... i read your update

Comment: Yeah, if you have to create file in your custom directory, then we need to create directory first.

Comment: You can accept the answer and upvote it. So it will use for other also.

Comment: after i create file...now problem is i write data to file is failed,  so could you help me

Comment: my update as below     NSError *error;
    Boolean success = [myData writeToFile:filePath options:0 error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"writeToFile failed with error %@", error);
    }